# Using Collections in Spring

Tags: java, spring

A collection object can be created from another collection object using constructor.

```
 List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>(someStudentList);
```

Which can be done in Spring.

```
     <bean id="stdArrayList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg >
            <list>
                <ref bean="student1" />
                <ref bean="student2" />
                <ref bean="student3" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="student1"  class="mawia.test.Student"
     ....
```

How can I do this way of adding item in Spring?

```
 Set<Student> set= new TreeSet<Student>();
        set.add(new Student(5, "Mawia"));
        ...
```

So that I can use the constructor which accept a comparator object.

```
 Set<Student> set= new TreeSet<Student>(new MyComparator());
        set.add(new Student(5, "Mawia"));
        ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the simplest approach would be to create a trivial subclass of `TreeSet` that provides a two-argument constructor:

```
public class MyTreeSet<T> extends TreeSet<T> {
  public MyTreeSet(Comparator<? super T> cmp, Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    super(cmp);
    addAll(coll);
  }
}
```

and use this as the type of your bean, passing both the comparator and the initial values as `<constructor-arg>` values.

```
<bean id="studentSet" class="com.example.MyTreeSet">
  <constructor-arg index="0">
    <bean class="com.example.MyComparator" />
  </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg index="1">
    <list>
      <ref bean="student1" />
      <ref bean="student2" />
      <ref bean="student3" />
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Or instead of a subclass of `TreeSet` you could write your own `FactoryBean`.

To do it without writing any additional code you could use a second bean definition to do the adding

```
<bean id="studentSet" class="java.util.TreeSet">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="com.example.MyComparator" />
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="studentSetFiller" factory-bean="studentSet" factory-method="addAll">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <ref bean="student1" />
      <ref bean="student2" />
      <ref bean="student3" />
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

but then any other bean into which you inject `studentSet` needs an additional `depends-on="studentSetFiller"` to make sure the set is populated before the target bean tries to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it using the `util` schema like this;

```
<util:set id="emails" set-class="java.util.TreeSet">
    <value>pechorin@hero.org</value>
    <value>raskolnikov@slums.org</value>
    <value>stavrogin@gov.org</value>
    <value>porfiry@gov.org</value>
</util:set>
```

(taken from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-set)

I'll test if its possible to add constructor args and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The TreeSet does not provide a combined constructor to pass Comparator as well as data. So I guess you can only do one via construtor injection.

Other part you should try via property injection if its exposed.